# What does $$ (double dollar) mean in Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, jdbc, sqlplus, dollar-sign

This Create package query executes in a SQLPlus util cli without error -

```sql
create or replace package PACKAGE2 as 
$if $$install_ad_zd_sys $then 
procedure LOG( X_MODULE varchar2, X_LEVEL varchar2, X_MESSAGE varchar2); 
function LITERAL(X_VALUE varchar2) return varchar2; 

else procedure LOG_VER; 

$end 
end;
/
```

Just want to know what does double dollar mean here?
Is it a sqlplus specific keyword?

I tried running this whole block as part of jdbc but it gives error 'Invalid column index'. So, I am suspecting the sign is specific to sqlplus, but not able to find the meaning of it.

This is how I am executing the above sql in java jdbc

```html
plSqlstatement = connection.prepareCall(sqlBuffer.toString());
//sqlBuffer contains the whole create package block
//like sqlBuffer.append("CREATE OR REPLACE
//PACKAGE ....").append("/n").append(..next Line) and so on.
```

Comment: The error seems to be down to how you are running the block from JDBC rather than what it contains.

Comment: @AlexPoole yes, it was due to CallableStatement.execute().
Instead, I used Statement.execute(sqlBuffer.toString()) and it worked.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an [inquiry directive](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/plsql-language-fundamentals.html#GUID-E918087C-D5A8-4CEE-841B-5333DE6D4C15):

> An inquiry directive provides information about the compilation environment.

> An inquiry directive typically appears in the *boolean_static_expression* of a selection directive, ...

... which is how you are using it, as it's within the `$if` conditional compilation directive.

You would need to [assign a value](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/plsql-language-fundamentals.html#GUID-623713EB-4FD1-4C8B-955C-4135342F5F68), which you don't seem to be doing in either execution. But it will compile anyway, through SQL*Plus or JDBC (as in [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=d82ed92acb8cacd4b8f3c338553ec7ec)).

If you are getting an error from your JDBC call then you need to look at how you are running it - particularly if you are making get/set calls for arguments, as the error message suggests - since there are no arguments to set or retrieve.

Comment: Thanks, you comment points me to a direction now. I have updated the question with jdbc details.
I think I need to check how CREATE commands are run in jdbc.
My code works for a BEGIN...END block, so I assumed CREATE works the same way.